# I can't get the correct location of my finger on android touch event

Tags: java, android, position, touch, draw

I have a problem taking my finger's location on the onTouch event on a ImageView. Basically I get the location of my finger's touch and then i start to draw a line, but the location that i draw it's so different from my touch location. I put my code and I explain it:

First I get the touch location with this method:

```
 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    if (first == true)
    {
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(x) + " " + String.valueOf(y), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        first = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (event.getHistorySize() == 0) 
        {
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
        }

        if (x == 0 && y == 0) 
        {
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();   
        }

        canvas.drawLine(x, y, event.getX(), event.getY(), paint);
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        imageView.invalidate();
    }
    return true;    
}
```

And then I use this other method to draw a line when I make click on one button:

```
public void btnMove_Click(View view)
{
    if(orientation == "UP")
    {
        canvas.drawLine(x, y, x, y - pixelFoot, paint); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dibujado en " + String.valueOf(x) + " " + String.valueOf(y), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        y -= pixelFoot;
        imageView.invalidate();
    }
    else if(orientation == "DOWN")  
    {
        canvas.drawLine(x, y, x, y + pixelFoot, paint);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dibujado en " + String.valueOf(x) + " " + String.valueOf(y), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        y += pixelFoot;
        imageView.invalidate();         
    }
    else if(orientation == "LEFT")
    {
        canvas.drawLine(x, y, x - pixelFoot, y, paint);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dibujado en " + String.valueOf(x) + " " + String.valueOf(y), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        x -= pixelFoot;
        imageView.invalidate();         
    }
    else if(orientation == "RIGHT")
    {
        canvas.drawLine(x, y, x + pixelFoot, y, paint);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dibujado en " + String.valueOf(x) + " " + String.valueOf(y), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        x += pixelFoot;
        imageView.invalidate();         
    }
}
```

The X and Y values I recieve on the btnMove_Click code are the same that on the onTouch event, but the line position is different. (I get the "bad" X and Y positions by clicking on the line position when it was drawed)

The results I get are the next:

1. First:

   - X and Y values when I touch with my finger:  X=572 Y=389
   - X and Y values when the line is drawed:  X=648 Y=370
2. Second:

   - X and Y values when I    touch with my finger:  X=648 Y=370
   - X and Y values when the line is    drawed:  X=704 Y=348
3. Third:

   - X and Y values when I    touch with my finger:     X=270 Y=228
   - X and Y values when the line    is drawed:  X=435 Y=250.

My XML Layout File is the next:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="800px"
        android:layout_height="564px"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFingerPaint"
            android:layout_width="800px"
            android:layout_height="564px"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Also I see the ImageView is smaller in ADV than in design view, I don't know why. And if I made the touch event near the right margin of the imageView, the X's and Y's error is less than if I do it in other position more on the left.

Comment: when you toast it you get the right values??

Comment: Yes, the toast give me the same values in both situations. When I made the initial touch and when I push the button, but the line position is totally different. I'll add the drawLine button code if it could help. Thanks!